# move_uploaded_file() function doesn't work on server?

Tags: php, html, web, file-upload, server

I have a website that allows a user to upload an image using PHP move_uploaded_file() and a PHP form. On local development the upload works fine and the image is copied from the users computer into the '/library/uploads' folder within the site directory.

Although once I've put the site on the web server it doesn't add the image to the folder anymore. Here's my code below:

PHP `move_uploaded_file()` code:

```
if($_FILES['myfile']['name'])
        {
          //if no errors...
          if(!$_FILES['myfile']['error'])
          {
            //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
            $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']); //rename file
            if($_FILES['myfile']['size'] > (102400000)) //can't be larger than 100 MB
            {
              $valid_file = false;
              $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
            }

            //if the file has passed the test
            if($valid_file)
            {
              //move it to where we want it to be
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], '/library/uploads/'.$_FILES['myfile']['name']);
              $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
            }
          }
          //if there is an error...
          else
          {
            //set that to be the returned message
            $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['myfile']['error'];
          }
        }
```

Form code:

```
<form class="search-form__form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="myfile" /> 

    <input class="search-form__button" name="submit-service" type="submit" value="Submit Service ">


    <div class="search-form__form-message">
      <p class="search-form__error-message"><?php echo $message; ?></p>
    </div>

  </form>
```

And here's my web server directory:

[image]

Comment: Whats the error you are getting

Comment: sounds like permission issue to me

Comment: check with folder permission

Comment: I've checked with the hosting provider (NameCheap) and they say there aren't any permissions set up but I'll have another look, cheers.

Also no errors are showing.

Comment: permission of the folder must be 0777

Answer (score 1):

The function is not calling because the variable $valid_file is not define 
first at the top define it as 
$valid_file  = true;

then in if condition check

```
if($valid_file == true){
// do upload file
} else{
// error show (Because if it goes in anather if it will go the the false and file will not upload)
} here i update your code



$valid_file = true;
if($_FILES['myfile']['name'])
        {
          //if no errors...
          if(!$_FILES['myfile']['error'])
          {
            //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
            $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']); //rename file
            if($_FILES['myfile']['size'] > (102400000)) //can't be larger than 100 MB
            {
              $valid_file = false;
              $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
            }

            //if the file has passed the test
            if($valid_file == true)
            {
              //move it to where we want it to be
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], '/library/uploads/'.$_FILES['myfile']['name']);
              $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
            }
          }
          //if there is an error...
          else
          {
            //set that to be the returned message
            $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['myfile']['error'];
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) This now runs the code and gives me the message that the file was accepted but the file still isn't on the server. Must be something to do with the server hmm...

Comment: ok if file is accepted it means it's on the server but not in that folder where it should be check other folder. File must be in public/"your desire folder"